# Can Android default player play videos ONLY on fullscreen?

Tags: android, video, fullscreen

I've implemented a very simple app that takes an rtsp address and launches the video.
The player always takes the whole screen. Is it possible in Android to play the clip on just a defined area of the screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a videoview to define what area of the screen u want to use for play videos

You have an example in the android examples 
[videoview demo android](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html)